# Unrecognized configuration section system.net (.NET 6/.NET Core)

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, .net-6.0

I am trying to use the **system.net** section in **app.config** in .Net 6, but it fails:

*System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 'Configuration system failed to initialize'
Inner exception:
ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section system.net*

Any idea what the problem is?

---

The program:

```
using System.Configuration;
string? bogus = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Bogus"];
Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {bogus}!");
```

The app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" useNagleAlgorithm="false" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="Bogus" value="Bogus" />
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

The csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: in .NET Core (and therefore .NET 6) working with configuration changed a lot. Please check out the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration) (and for [ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0))

Comment: *system.net* not supported https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24083

Answer (score 2):

Apparently [it's not supported anymore](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/33523#issuecomment-598999154):

> This is by design, you can't have sections under *configuration* that
> don't have definitions. system.net is normally defined in
> *machine.config*, but there isn't a definition for .NET Core as the type
> (System.Net.Configuration.NetSectionGroup) doesn't exist in Core.